# VBA: Code review

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel macro, but have basic understanding.

I am trying to find a max value from Sheet1, where I have the code but want to know how I get the same result if I run this code from any other sheets I have on my workbook.

```
Sub FindMaxDate()
Set Worksheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
MsgBox CDate(Max_date)
End Sub
```

For example: I have date filed on Sheet1.Range("A:A") and the max date available there is 01.01.2018 (Cod will give me the same value), but if I am on Sheet2 and run this code it will take value from Sheet2 and show me "12:00:00 AM".

Some one please help me to correct this code so that it will always show the max value from Sheet1 ( 01.01.2018 )

Hope you guys get my queston. Else please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: `...Max(Worksheet.Columns("A"))`

Comment: Write a `Do Loop` for each `Sheets` in your `Worksheet`

Comment: You should watch this series:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 6 - Worksheets, Charts and Sheets](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=M3OE7Z62oGM&index=6&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: @ScottCraner - Probably not the best practice to use `worksheet` as the name of a var since it is a var type, specifically the exact type you would need if declarations were required with `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @Jeeped I just fixed the one problem hence the comment and not an answer. But yes, one should not use that and also declare all variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FindMaxDate()
Set Worksheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheet.Columns("A"))
MsgBox CDate(Max_date)
End Sub
```

Comment: Once the OP gets used to using `Option Explicit` (generally considered 'best practice'), how is that var going to be declared?

Comment: @Jeeped `Dim Worksheet As Worksheet` is perfectly legal. Confusing, perhaps, but legal. That said this is a terrible answer by any standards.